# OpenLayers "Text" layer always visible on load

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to load a layer as an overlay and make it initially not visible

```
    airBoss = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "AirBoss Locations", { location:"./airboss.txt"} , {
    visibility: false, isBaseLayer: false, displayInLayerSwitcher: true});
    map.addLayer(airBoss);
    airBoss.setZIndex(210);
    airBoss.setVisibility = false;
```

Using this code with or without the additional "setVisibility" line the layer always is visible.  Is this a bug in the JavaScript of OpenLayers or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setVisibility()` is a function not an attribute.  You just need to change the last line of your sample code to  `airBoss.setVisibility(false)`

ref: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.setVisibility

Comment: Duh !!  Thanks of course. Thanks for the answer I'll try it today.

Comment: Works perfeectly now, however even though I have   displayInLayerSwitcher: false (changed the code) it still shows it in the layer switcher

Comment: @MB - same question was just asked today.  check it out. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31370/how-can-i-remove-a-layer-from-layerswitcher-in-openlayers

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I have in my script tried with and without the single quote marks.  I think it works for WMS layers not text layers though