# How can I remove a layer from layerswitcher in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I have several vectors and WMS layers in layer switcher. But I don't need these layers to be displaying in layer switcher. How can I remove these layers from layer switcher?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The option, displayInLayerSwitcher is True by default. You must pass this parameter explicitly with the False arguement. http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html

```js
var ol_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS","http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
    {layers: 'basic'},
    {'displayInLayerSwitcher':false}
);
```

Comment: @Mohammedshafeek If the answer works for you, consider accepting it so the author can get true internet karma based thanks